# Parallel axis theorem proof?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

First, I thought theorems do not have proofs. Anyway, for [parallel axis theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem), I was given that the addition of translational kinetic energy and rotational kinetic energy proves the parallel axis theorem. I am confused how that happens, although I can see it mathematically. But I cannot understand, what does translational kinetic energy has to do with trying to find the equivalent of inertia of an object that rotates in a different that its centre of mass axis. I don't see where the translational kinetic energy occurs in that example! I would expect in that case the object would have a rotational kinetic energy with an Igg different than the regular Igg which is calculated in respect to the centre of mass axis. But how can we add the translational kinetic energy and then assume that the sum of it with the rotational kinetic energy will help us calculate the Izz? Can you clarify this to me please?

Comment: "First, I thought theorems do not have proofs." /quote From the [Wikipedia article on "theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem): "In mathematics, a theorem is a statement that has been **proven** on the basis of previously established statements".

Comment: If theorems don't have proofs, you should tell that to the millions of mathematicians who have been proving theorems over the years...

Comment: Regarding your first sentence, see [Difference between axioms, theorems, postulates, corollaries, and hypotheses](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/7717/36057)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what proof of the PAT you are referring to which involves using translational or kinetic energy.

The PAT can be proved by using the relationship which exists between two different coordinate systems.

This proof is clearly shown here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem

and in many other references on mechancs.

Comment: Basically, my tutor said for an object that has both rotational and translational kinetic energy, it is E = 1/2mV^2 + 1/2Iggw^2. And if you replace V=rw and the factorize, you get 1/2(mr^2+Igg)w^2 and he says that the mr^2+Igg is the Izz.

Comment: Anyone please? What does the 1/2mV^2 + 1/2Iggw^2 really stand for? From that he deducted that Izz = mr^2 +  Igg! How???